# Entity Framework Core error not seen before Class.TempProperty is of type 'object' which is not supported by current database provider

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core `code-first` with fluent API entity configurations, in an ASP .NET MVC Core application. My code currently compiles, but when I run add-migration in the Package Manager Console, it gives the error below:

> The property 'Exam.TempId' is of type 'object' which is not supported
>   by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or
>   manually configure the database type for it.

Searching Google for this error yields no results. Can anybody here help please?

"Exam" is a class in my domain model, but it doesn't have a "TempId" property so I guess that's something that Entity Framework is adding. It does have an "Id" property, but the type is int, not object.

I'll start by sharing the Exam class and the Exam configuration class. I can share more code if required. I'd be really grateful for any advice you can provide to resolve the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace MySite.Core.Models
{
    public class Exam : ActivatableEntity
    {
        private int _numberOfQuestionsToBeAttempted;

        private Exam()
        {
            Topics = new Collection<Topic>();
        }

        public Exam(IUser createdByUser,
            string name,
            string description,
            double timeAllowedInMinutes,
            bool shuffleTopicsTogether = true) :
            base(createdByUser)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            Topics = new Collection<Topic>();
            TimeAllowedInMinutes = timeAllowedInMinutes;
            ShuffleTopicsTogether = shuffleTopicsTogether;
        } 

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public string Description { get; private set; }

        public double TimeAllowedInMinutes { get; private set; }

        public bool ShuffleTopicsTogether { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerable<Question> PossibleQuestions
        {
            get
            {
                return Topics.SelectMany(t => t.PossibleQuestions);
            }
        }

        public int NumberOfQuestionsToBeAttempted
        {
            get
            {
                if (_numberOfQuestionsToBeAttempted != 0) return _numberOfQuestionsToBeAttempted;
                foreach (Topic topic in Topics)
                {
                    _numberOfQuestionsToBeAttempted += topic.NumberOfQuestionsToBeAttempted;
                }
                return _numberOfQuestionsToBeAttempted;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Topic> Topics { get;  }

        public void Update(IUser updatedByUser, string name, string description, double timeAllowedInMinutes, bool shuffleTopicsTogether = true)
        {
            Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            Description = description;
            TimeAllowedInMinutes = timeAllowedInMinutes;
            ShuffleTopicsTogether = shuffleTopicsTogether;
            Update(updatedByUser);
        }
    }
}
```

Exam configuration class

```
using MySite.Core.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace MySite.Persistence.EntityConfiguration
{
    public class ExamConfiguration
    {
        public ExamConfiguration(EntityTypeBuilder<Exam> entityBuilder)
        {
            entityBuilder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            entityBuilder.HasOne(e => (ApplicationUser)e.CreatedByUser)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedByUserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            entityBuilder.HasOne(e => (ApplicationUser)e.LastUpdatedByUser)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.LastUpdatedByUserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            entityBuilder.Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

            entityBuilder.Property(e => e.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250);

            entityBuilder.HasMany(e => e.Topics)
                .WithOne(t => t.Exam).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
}
```

As requested by posters, I'm adding the code for the base classes below:

```
using System;

namespace MySite.Core.Models
{
    public abstract class ActivatableEntity :
        UpdatableCreatableEntity,
        IActivatable
    {
        protected ActivatableEntity() { }

        protected ActivatableEntity(IUser createdByUser) : base(createdByUser) { }

        public int? LastActivatedByUserId { get; private set; }
        public IUser LastActivatedByUser { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? WhenLastActivated { get; private set; }
        public int? LastDeactivatedByUserId { get; private set; }
        public IUser LastDeactivatedByUser { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? WhenLastDeactivated { get; private set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; private set; }

        protected virtual void Activate(IUser activatedByUser)
        {
            LastActivatedByUser = activatedByUser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(activatedByUser));

            LastActivatedByUserId = activatedByUser.Id;
            WhenLastActivated = DateTime.Now;
            IsActive = true;
        }

        protected virtual void Deactivate(IUser deactivatedByUser)
        {
            LastDeactivatedByUser = deactivatedByUser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(deactivatedByUser));

            LastDeactivatedByUserId = deactivatedByUser.Id;
            WhenLastDeactivated = DateTime.Now;
            IsActive = false;
        }
    }

    public abstract class UpdatableCreatableEntity :
        CreatableEntity,
        IUpdatable
    {
        protected UpdatableCreatableEntity() { }

        protected UpdatableCreatableEntity(IUser createdByUser) : base(createdByUser) { }

        public int? LastUpdatedByUserId { get; private set; }
        public IUser LastUpdatedByUser { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? WhenLastUpdated { get; private set; }

        protected virtual void Update(IUser updatedByUser)
        {
            LastUpdatedByUser = updatedByUser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(updatedByUser));
            LastUpdatedByUserId = updatedByUser.Id;
            WhenLastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public abstract class CreatableEntity :
        IIdentifiable,
        ICreatable
    {
        protected CreatableEntity() { }

        protected CreatableEntity(IUser createdByUser)
        {
            CreatedByUser = createdByUser ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(createdByUser));
            CreatedByUserId = createdByUser.Id;
            WhenCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public int? CreatedByUserId { get; private set; }
        public DateTime WhenCreated { get; private set; }
        public IUser CreatedByUser { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the base classes (like `ActivatableEntity` etc.)

Comment: Any one of the base class in the hierarchy has TypeId for sure

Comment: Thanks for your interest! Sure I can share the base classes. I have edited the original post to include them.

Comment: I just did a search in the entire solution for the word "TempId". No results found.

Comment: Check for entity class called `Temp` having collection (or enumerable) of `Exam`.

Comment: ShadowProperty is being hit probably as a result of a inherited base class, either create an Id for Exam class object or change how you have created the base class...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties

Comment: `public int Id { get; private set; }`  <<<<<<<<< private is causing this

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!

I got to the bottom of it, finally, after removing all my domain classes except `ApplicationUser` and then meticulously adding them back one at a time to find which one caused the problem. It took hours checking the entity and configuration code and trying a new database migration each time but it paid off eventually.

There was never any property in the solution called `TempId`, nor was there an entity class called `Temp` with an enumerable or collection of type `Exam`.

Comment: I believe what caused it was another domain class called `Question`, which had a property of type `object` called `ExamId`. I never found out why the error referred to `TempId`.

Comment: Here's what else I learned:

I removed all the foreign key properties (such as `ExamId`, `TopicId`, `UserId`) from my model. I thought they were necessary (or at least a common practice) from watching tutorials on the internet but I now believe they are completely redundant in Entity Framework Core. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you should always just stick to navigation properties without exposing foreign key properties to keep the model nice and lean and the configuration simple. I mean, you can always say `Exam.Topic.Id` instead of `Exam.TopicId`

Comment: Next thing I learnt was that the order in which you do your fluent API configuration really matters. If your foreign key is a composite of two foreign keys you must configure in the following order:

1. Define navigation properties first. `entityBuilder.HasOne(a => a.Candidate)` and `entityBuilder.HasOne(a => a.Exam)`
2. Define shadow properties representing foreign keys of each navigation property. `entityBuilder.Property<int>("CandidateId")` and `entityBuilder.Property<int>("ExamId")`
3. Lastly, define the composite primary key.  `entityBuilder.HasKey("ExamId", "CandidateId")`

Comment: Optionally, so that the code still works when class names and property names are changed, I used C#'s `nameof(Property)` feature instead of the magic strings "ExamId" and "CandidateId"

Comment: I didn't saw your comments here while I was posting my answer, but I've jumped to the same conclusion as you, and decided to report problem to developers.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and it confused me a lot. But luckily I was using version control, so I was able to trace reasons of the issue.

For me it was `many-to-many` relation entity model with constructor that assigns values to fields. I was relying to Visual Studio to generate properties for me automatically, and `VS` did poor job not detecting type of the property that later became a key.

`VS` created property of type `object`, which is too generic and hardly could be translated into underlying database abstractions. Hence the error.

I agree, quite not descriptive, hope they will fix that in future versions.

So try to search for properties of `object` type and check, are they used as keys, if yes, try to replace them with specific types supported by your database provider.

Reported error for developers: [#9817](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9817).